# Error with Ref parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, ref

```
    public Resultado Procesar_Respuesta_Estructurada(ref object ObjetoIN, ref string Login, string NombreMetodo)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Resultado ObjetoOUT = default(Resultado);
        bool Errors_Warning = false;
        Utilitarios OUtil = default(Utilitarios);
        try
        {

            OUtil = new Utilitarios();
            ObjetoOUT = new Resultado();

            ObjetoOUT.Success =  ObjetoIN.Success;
            ObjetoOUT.ExistWarnings = ObjetoIN.ExistWarnings;
            ObjetoOUT.Items = ObjetoIN.Items;

            if ((ObjetoIN.Errors != null) && ObjetoIN.Errors.Length > 0)
            {
                Errors_Warning = true;
```

the error is in ObjetoIN.Success

Error   3   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Success' and no extension method 'Success' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `ref`. The type of `ObjetoIN` is specified as `object`. However, object doesn't have a property or a field named `Success` and that's what the error message is telling you. You need to supply a valid type for `ObjetoIN` before you can access `Success`.

Comment: Yes, maybe it should be `ref Resultado ObjetoIN` (the first parameter) instead?